# Should ascribing things to "the Jews" collectively on SE sites be disallowed?

Tags: discussion, policy, code-of-conduct

I came across the question [Under the laws of which regime was Jesus sentenced to death on the cross?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/95224/) on HNQ, but I'm not a member there and don't think this policy question is really site-specific (it also applies to one or more other SE sites discussing religion) so I'm asking it here.

In that question, it really surprised me to see the collective wording "the Jews", in:

> The Jews got Jesus killed

and

> This is the trump card the Jews used to get Jesus crucified.

etc.

Is this kind of usage ok on SE sites, and should it be tolerated?

I realize this is somewhat standard in this kind of context, but it's also a very anti-Semitic trope, and I believe the poor/imprecise wording should be disallowed on SE sites as such. Instead, someone who wants to discuss this type of topic can ascribe these accusations to specific individuals or groups of people, rather than "the Jews".

Comment: Is your preference that when discussing *the Bible* people should actually write "individuals Jesus killed. These individuals may or may not have been Jewish. Even though they prosecuted Jesus based on the Jewish laws and religion. But they weren't necessarily Jewish in order to not paint the Jewish as having killed Jesus" or otherwise try very hard to avoid what's actually in the Bible? Because, to me, seems that context is key here.

Comment: We shouldn't ever need to force something that common sense takes care of. We can't just ban every collective usage. Why should this case be special? Common sense dictates that "Americans" or "women" or "teenagers" are not a homogeneous group either.

Comment: Supposedly the arrest was made by order of Caiaphas. Caiaphas was a high priest of the temple, a Jew. However, the Sanhedrin was likely involved too. And who knows how many others. Detailing who was and wasn't involved is probably outside the scope of the question. Which language would you have preferred instead that's both more detailed yet inclusive enough to mention all the characters?

Comment: @M.A.R. I've not seen any answer which attributed the death of say even Anne Frank being killed by "the Germans", MLK by "the Americans" or Jeanne d'Arc by "the men" for exactly this reason.  It's so imprecise it's bordering on wrong.  Given the nature of antisemitic tropes this just emphasizes the issue here much more.

Comment: @VLAZ: I don't know enough details myself but based on Mast's comment, something like "Caiaphas and other Jewish leaders who opposed Jesus" would be fairly precise wording that's not attributing the action to an entire religious/ethnic group - a group which has historically been subjected to genocide **largely on the basis of this very attribution**.

Comment: (*"ICE"* is probably *[U.S. Immigration and Customs Enforcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Immigration_and_Customs_Enforcement)*.)

Comment: The average 10 year old who's gone to school knows this much: Aren't they kind of missing the point that Jesus was Jewish himself? All references to religion in the Bible are references to Judaism - since per definition Christianity didn't exist prior to Christ - Christianity is a reinterpretation of an already existing religion, which appears with Jesus and does not exist before that. The only people who aren't Jewish in the New Testament would be the Romans. None of this is by any means controversial to anyone but extremists of one religion or the other.

Comment: @Lundin: The average 10 year old does not know the history of anti-Semitism and the Holocaust and how this collective attribution contributed to genocide. Without active education on the matter, they might, like the average frequenter of Meta SE, think this is a silly non-issue...

Comment: My point: how can it be anti-Semitism if the Bible says that Jews kill another Jew? They didn't want to kill him _because_ he was a Jew (the definition of anti-Semitism), but rather because they thought he was a bad one. It's like calling the current demonstrants against the government in Israel "anti-Semitic". Referring to a religious group in plural is not "anti-Semitic" either. And as the average 10 year old knows, Jesus was _not_ killed by Jews, but by the Romans...

Comment: Later translations of the Bible to English may very well be anti-Semitic, but if so I don't see how it is SE's job to fix that... We can ban any religious extremists of any religion from posting here though.

Comment: @Lundin: I didn't ask SE to "fix that" or "fix the Bible". I asked that SE disallow folks from using formulatic genocide-incidement via collective attribution in *their own words* when discussing the topic. It's the non-critical repetition of that wording, not the presence of quotations or discussions of it, that should be against any decent CoC.

Answer (score 10):

It's important to look at this in context. From the question (emphasis added):

> And we see the Jewish leaders saying to Pilate:
>
> > **The Jews** answered him, “We have a law, and according to that law he ought to die because he has claimed to be the Son of God.” (Jn 19:7)

While the rest of the wording of the quote varies (and even the spelling!), about 40 English-language Bibles (the majority) use "the Jews" here according to BibleHub (see the [full list](https://biblehub.com/parallel/john/19-7.htm) or the [page with Greek](https://biblehub.com/john/19-7.htm)). This includes well-known ones such as the King James Version. (OP, in contrast, uses "the Jewish leaders" which is only used in a few Bibles.)

Because of this academic context, I don't see this as a CoC violation. Either way, you are free to either flag for moderator attention or [contact the CMs directly](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/contact) to get another opinion, but it seems likely that the wording will stand, at least here.

In other contexts, sure, using "the Jews" can be a harmful generalization, and either [rewording](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/329153/41273) or flagging the content for removal would be appropriate.

Comment: I'm aware of the context, and said so in the question. I can see how that makes *quoting* of the source text arguably acceptable, but I don't believe it excuses non-critical restatement of the collective attribution, especially when this attribution is one of the core tenets of anti-Semitism: blaming "the Jews" collectively for "killing Jesus".

Answer (score 0):

- You can try raising it with the moderators of that site either by flagging or by creating a meta post on that site.
- If you don't want to, or the response to the above step doesn't satisfy you you can always seek help from [Community Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)

This really applies to any post you take issue with.